# Apache FOP- need to create multi page table starting from middle of first page

Tags: java, pdf, xslt, oracle-adf, apache-fop

I am using FOP version 2.0. My template has some text paragraphs on first page after which there is a dynamic table with n number of rows.

```
...
</fo:block-container>
      <fo:block-container height="0.5cm" width="7.40cm" top="8.80cm"
                          left="0.3cm" padding=".4mm" position="absolute">
        <fo:block text-align="start" space-after.optimum="3pt"
                  line-height="14pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12pt">Header
                                                                               Options</fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>
      <fo:block-container border-style="solid" border-width=".5mm"
                          height="1.00cm" width="16.40cm" top="8.80cm"
                          left="3.40cm" padding=".4mm" position="absolute">
        <fo:block text-align="start" space-after.optimum="3pt"
                  line-height="14pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12pt">$header.miscInfo</fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>
      <fo:block-container width="17.40cm" top="10.30cm"
                          left="0.40cm" padding=".4mm" >
        <fo:block page-break-before="always">
        <fo:table border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="thick">
          <fo:table-body font-size="12pt" font-family="sans-serif">
            <fo:table-row border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-color="#000"
                          border-bottom-width="thick">
...
```

The table is enclosed by a fo:block in turn enclosed into a fo:block-container. 
I included `<fo:block page-break-before="always">` to break the long table in multiple pages. But on using this the table starts from the 2nd page and the remaining area on first page remains blank.

**I want my table to start from the the first page after the preceeding block-containers.**

Comment: I used <fo:block page-break-before="always"> to break the long  table in multiple pages. But this is causing the table to start from the 2nd page  and the remaining area on first page remains blank. I want my table to start from the the first page itself after the preceding block-containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in your template affecting the placing and breaking of the table.

### Absolutely positioned blocks

The "header" paragraphs are placed inside absolutely positioned blocks: this means that during processing they are taken out of the normal flow and they have no impact on the layout of later siblings ([see the XSL-FO recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#absolute-position)).

**Solution:** remove `position="absolute" top="..." left="..."` and use spaces / margins instead (note that the `top` and `left` attributes on the `fo:block-container` around the table have no effect, as that block is not absolutely positioned). You can avoid using `fo:block-container` altogether, and use normal `fo:block` elements.

### Breaks

The property `page-break-before="always"` on an `fo:block` element has the effect of placing a page-break before the content of that block, which is exactly *what you were trying to avoid*.

**Solution:** remove the break property.

With the suggested changes headers and table are part of the normal content flow and their contents are placed consecutively in the pages.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I removed the block-container encircling the fo:table and used the margin-properties of the  block and removed break-page attribute. This did the trick and now my table starts from the first page itself after preceding text.  However i am facing one more small issue. The table layout is perfect till the rows on first page. But when it continues on the 2nd page, the columns are shifted to the right by some margin and the last column becomes invisible. Any insight on this what may be the reason? Thanks once again.

Comment: @Akash It's quite difficult to say what could be going wrong without looking at the modified table and the page masters; besides, this should probably be a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have put another question for this with more details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442963/apache-fop-table-component-getting-misaligned-from-second-page-onwards                      Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that you *want* a page break before it by using that attribute. Just remote the page-break-before attribute.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The page-break-before attribute was not required. The issue got solved but there's another issue that i am now facing which i have spelled out in the comments of the other answer. Kindly have a look into that and see if you can suggest something. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, well if the answer solved your issue consider accepting the answer and asking another question.